# Share Dialog Facebook Mobile Blank

Tags: facebook, api, mobile, share

Adding / tag friends in the "Share Dialog" from mobile phones, the screen becomes blank. 
The "Share Dialog" if it is visible but when pressing the "Add friends" button, the screen turns white. The other options work well.
Version 2.1